# In DAX, is the Whole Number "0" = Blank?

Tags: powerbi, dax

just trying to build a new column in Power BI through DAX

I am not sure why if the data COB to COB@ is Zero or Blank, the result will show BLANK
so, if the COB to COB@ data is showing 0, how can i show it as "0:00"?
Thank you!

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use == instead of just = if you want to be strict with your comparison.

Comment: Thank you! I found isblank() could help as well, just fyi to the rest of the people who may have the same question, thank you!!